# Does my newborn sleep too little?

Tags: sleep, newborn, night-time

My 8 day old daughter has slept about 13 hours during last 24 hours. She eats a lot, poops often and properly (at least 7 times in 24h), is breast fed and there is enough milk for her.

Is that normal? Supposedly, newborns should sleep much more. Should I be worried?

Comment: one of mine had "sleeping days" and "awake days". Also 8 days could be a growth spurt so being awake to eat a lot could be temporary ... until 2 weeks rolls around :-)

Comment: @Chrys Holy .. cracker, this could be it - in the evening we put on her a cloth which we could have sworm fit her 5 days ago in the hospital, but now was too small. I'll accept such answer if she behaves "normally" in the next day or two.

Comment: @Chrys: You should post that as an answer! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Chrys' comment is correct.

Also, it takes a while for the baby to find and settle into her own personal rhythm, and there is lots of variation between babies. You're probably right that 13 hours per day is on the low side but that doesn't automatically make it something to worry over. Give it two more weeks and you'll see a sleep pattern.

You can also try to introduce your own schedule, for instance do the sleep/feeding/diaper-change routine on a 3- or 4-hour basis regardless of whether she's crying for it or not. With luck, this could help her into an evenly spaced rhythm that you can plan into your days and nights with reasonable precision. Some kids accept a rhythm like that, some don't. Wait and see.